# Using multiple programs simultaneously in Python

Tags: python, sockets, parallel-processing

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to write a script to automate a test.

How it works:
Program A: Sends commands through serial port waits for response and then executes next command
Program B: Uses a TCP_Client.exe app using Subprocess module to send arguments (ip, port, number of packets, size) along with the app to the command prompt and reads output.

What its supposed to do:

1. start tcp server on device accessed through serial port (Pyserial module) ===========> Program A
2. send "tcpclient.exe   ..." to command prompt. This will bind the socket and then prompt me to send some more commands through the serial port to the device. ==========> Program B
3. Send additional Commands to the device ==========> Program A
4. Enter a number to continue tcpclient.exe to next stage where packets are sent. ===========> Program B.
5. Wait for packets to be sent. Program sends a prompt saying done but does not quit. Waits for me to read data on device ===========> Program B
6. Send command through serial port to read data ==========> Program A
7. Go back to tcpclient.exe and quit the program. (basically need to hit a number followed by  to continue to finish.

```
RunSer2Command(lines2[21])
time.sleep(1)       
ls_output = subprocess.Popen(['tcpclient.exe','192.168.22.33','5000','100000','1400'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(1)
RunSer2Command(lines2[22])
RunSer2Command(lines2[23])
time.sleep(1)
ls_output = subprocess.Popen(['3'],stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
ls_output.communicate()

RunSer2Command(lines2[24])

ser2.close()
```

Something Like this

Could someone tell me if I should read up multi threading or is this too small to require it?
If so what should I be looking for?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.
Short answer is Threading will do it. It is also unnecessary. The subprocess module has enough for me to make it work. I just wasn't doing it right

```
RunSer2Command(lines2[21])
time.sleep(1)   
ls_output = subprocess.Popen(['tcpclient.exe','192.168.4.110','8000','10000','1400'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=3)
time.sleep(2)
RunSer2Command(lines2[22])
RunSer2Command(lines2[23])
time.sleep(1)
ls_output.communicate(input = '3')
ls_output.wait()
RunSer2Command(lines2[24])
```

For those who care threading route did get me to a certain point and I'll add that but I didn't go to the last condition since well... I found the easier route

```
def start_tcp_client(cond): 
    ls_output = subprocess.Popen(['tcpclient.exe','192.168.4.110','8000','1000','1400'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=3)
    with cond:
        cond.wait()
        ls_output.communicate(input = '3')
        ls_output.communicate()

def TCPSettings(cond):
    with cond:
        RunSer2Command(lines2[22])
        RunSer2Command(lines2[23])
        cond.notify()

    condition = threading.Condition()
    condition1 = threading.Condition()
    Client_thread=threading.Thread(name='Client_thread', target=start_tcp_client, args=(condition,))
    TCP_thread=threading.Thread(name='TCP_thread', target=TCPSettings, args=(condition,))
    RunSer2Command(lines2[21])
    time.sleep(2)   
    Client_thread.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    TCP_thread.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    Client_thread.join()
    time.sleep(10)
    RunSer2Command(lines2[24])
```

I still havent managed to work out all the kinks. There appear to be some timing issues. I'll update it once I get it working perfectly.